# Horizontal Overflow nav keep items in view

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar that overflows horizontally that I can scroll left/right with my finger on a phone. I can also swipe the main viewing area left/right, to change the selected nav item. When I do that, if the nav item isn't in view you can not see it unless you scroll.

Is there a way for me to bring the nav item into view if it is selected with the class `.active`?

```
/* The main container */
.container .categories {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 20px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: #000;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100vw;
}

/* The item within the container */
.container .categories span {
    padding: 20px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: solid 4px transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* The selected item */
.container .categories span.active {
    border-bottom: solid 4px #f47d25;
}
```

In `.container .categories span.active` Is there a way that I can make sure that the item is in the view when it is active?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x9wpbkrj/5/

Comment: It will be very helpful if you make jsfiddle.net !

Comment: @SohaibMohammed I have added a fiddle. as you can see selected item is not in view (if you have the viewport small enough). How can I force the selected item to be in view? (unless the user slides the nav left/right manually

Answer (score 0):

> https://jsfiddle.net/x9wpbkrj/4/

```css
body {
  color: white;
}

/* The main container */
.container .categories {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  /*overflow-x: scroll;*/
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
  /*position: fixed;*/
  line-height: 20px;
  z-index: 200;
  background: #000;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100vw;

  /*display: inline-block;*/
}


/* The item within the container */
.container .categories span {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-bottom: solid 4px transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* The selected item */
.container .categories span.active {
  border-bottom: solid 4px #f47d25;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="categories">
  <span>Trending</span>
  <span>New & Updated</span>
  <span>Discover</span>
  <span>Most Played</span>
  <span>Staff Picks</span>
  <span>New & Updated</span>
  <span>Discover</span>
  <span>Most Played</span>
  <span>Staff Picks</span>
  <span>New & Updated</span>
  <span>Discover</span>
  <span class="active">Most Played</span>
  <span>Staff Picks</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That just wraps the lines

Comment: There are a lot of items, May be you should sort these items in categories!

Comment: These are the categories.

Comment: Hmm! what you need to modify now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `scrollIntoView` might be the answer I am looking for:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

## Edit

The above works, but if an item is partially in view, it doesn't scroll. If I use `scrollLeft`, it seems to work pretty well.

```
$('.container .categories')[0].scrollLeft = 
$(`.container .categories > span:nth-child(${offset + 1})`)[0].offsetLeft;
```